# how to unset coolkie in php.i am click logout butten but cookie is not deleted

Tags: php, cookies

```
setcookie("cookie_name",$_SESSION['useremail'],time()+3600,"/beta","studentsponge.com");
setcookie("cookie_id",$_SESSION['userid'],time()+3600,"/beta","studentsponge.com");

// and unset cookie i use this.
//in logout butten   

if(isset($_COOKIE))
{ 
    setcookie("cookie_name",null,time()-3600,"/beta",".studentsponge.com");
    setcookie("cookie_id",null,time()-3600,"/beta",".studentsponge.com");

    unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
    unset($_COOKIE['cookie_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the expire time in the past, then the cookie will expire:

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("cookieName", "", time()-3600);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:

setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

https://www.php.net/function.setcookie

So when you click the logout button as opposed to unseting the cookie it's recommended that you setcookie to a time in the past:

```
<?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time()-3600);
?>
```

Shown @ http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp